# Android: How to force screen orientation for different screen sizes?

Tags: android

I use two different layout folders:

```
layout
layout-large
```

Now I want to ensure that the screen orientation is portrait if the `layout` folder is used, and landscape if the `layout-large` folder is used. How can I force this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct directory-name for the landscape layouts is 'layout-land', see [here](http://www.tekkie.ro/quick-n-dirty/how-to-change-your-layout-in-android-landscape-portrait-mode/).

If you do this, you don't need to do other things, Android will do the rest for you.

---

If you want to change to landscape based on the size of the Screen, you can [check for the screen-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions) and then set the Orientation using the ['setRequestedOrientation()'-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29) from the Activity class.

Comment: I want to force to use landscape mode if the screen is large. I think If I follow your advice, I just define the layout if landscape mode is used.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't get that from your question. I updated my answer, check out if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its too late.. But for what it's worth, you can define orientation in value for small screen and in value-large for large screen and then use it in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Have a look at [my blog post](http://capdroid.wordpress.com/2012/07/21/different-screen-orientation-on-different-screen-size/).

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this

```
supports-screens 
android:resizeable=["true"| "false"] 
android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"] 
android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"] 
android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"] 
android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"] 
android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"] 
android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer" 
android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer" 
android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer
```

It will handle your screen.

Answer (score -1):

Place to allactivities   `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in manifest like:

```
 <activity android:name=".View" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="Home">
        </activity>
```

Comment: Yes but then I'm using portrait orientation in both cases?